# How to pass identity token from AWS API Gateway using Cognito user pool to backend microservice api?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I have a .net API exposed through as a private REST API in AWS API gateway using a Congito UserPool authorizer.

The calling client app is a web (browser) application.

The API needs to need the user's identity - roles and userId, etc.

Can I somehow forward the Id token along to the backend in a header? How do I provide this information to the backend microservice?